# Hundreds of "has no member named..." Errors C++

Tags: c++, file, compilation, header, members

I've just started C++ programming so excuse me if this is a horrid noob mistake, but it's doing my head in.

I have multiple .cpp files correctly programmed and no errors after compiling them, all with their own .h files.

For some reason, when I try to compile one class named "flyingUnit.cpp" I get hundreds of errors, all along the lines of:

```
flyingUnit.cpp: In constructor ‘FlyingUnit::FlyingUnit(const char*, const char*, double, double,
bool, const char*, const char*, int, const char*)’:
flyingUnit.cpp:26:38: error: class ‘FlyingUnit’ does not have any field named ‘length’
             const char* weyr ) : length(length), wingspan(wingspan), age(age)
                                  ^
```

I have absolutely no idea as to why this is happening, everything used in the class is never found, left completely dumbfounded, when it seems to work perfectly fine with all the other classes. Why am I getting these errors?

## flyingUnit.h:

```
#ifndef FLYING_UNIT_H
#define FLYING_UNIT_H

#include "rider.h"
#include "dragon.h"
#include "fall.h"

const int MAX_FALLS = 20;

class FlyingUnit
{
public:
     FlyingUnit( ) = default;

FlyingUnit( const char* dragonName, const char* dragonColour,
            double length, double wingspan, bool breatheFire,
            const char* riderName, const char* rank, int age,
            const char* weyr );

void addFlyingUnit( const char* dragonName, const char* dragonColour,
            double length, double wingspan, bool breatheFire,
            const char* riderName, const char* rank, int age,
            const char* weyr );

void setRank( const char* rank );
void setWeyr( const char* weyr );

int getFallCount( ) const { return fallCount; }

void addFall( const char* location, int day, int month, int year );

friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const FlyingUnit& f );
friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, FlyingUnit & f );
friend ofstream& operator << (ofstream& os, const FlyingUnit& f );
friend ifstream& operator >> (ifstream& is, FlyingUnit& f ); 

const char* getRiderName( ) const;
const char* getDragonName( ) const;

private:
Rider rider;
Dragon dragon;
Fall falls[ MAX_FALLS ];
int fallCount = 0; 
};
#endif
```

## flyingUnit.cpp:

```
#include "flyingUnit.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
  return 0;
}

FlyingUnit::FlyingUnit( const char* dragonName, const char* dragonColour,
                double length, double wingspan, bool breatheFire,
                const char* riderName, const char* rank, int age,
                const char* weyr ) : length(length), wingspan(wingspan), age(age)
            {
              strcpy(this->dragonName, dragonName);
              strcpy(this->dragonColour, dragonColour);

              this->breatheFire = breatheFire;
              strcpy(this->riderName, riderName);
              strcpy(this->rank, rank);

              strcpy(this->weyr, weyr);

            }

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const FlyingUnit& f)
{
  os << "Dragon Name: " << f.dragonName
     << "Dragon Colour: " << f.dragonColour
     << "Length: " << f.length
     << "Wingspan: " << f.wingspan
     << "Breathes Fire: " << f.breatheFire
     << "Rider Name: " << f.riderName
     << "Rank: " << f.rank
     << "Age: " << f.age
     << "Weyr: " << f.weyr << endl;

     return os;

}

istream& operator >> (istream& is, FlyingUnit & f)
{
    char temp[500];
    cout << "Enter Dragon Name: ";
    is.getline(temp, 500);
    strcpy(f.dragonName, temp);

    cout << "Enter Dragon Colour: ";
    is.getline(temp, 500);
    strcpy(f.dragonColour);

    cout << "Length: ";
    is >> f.length;
    is.ignore(100000, "\n");

    cout << "Wingspan: ";
    is >> f.wingspan;
    is.ignore(100000, "\n");

    //cout << "Breathes Fire: ";
   // is.getline(temp, 500);

   cout << "Enter Rider Name: ";
    is.getline(temp, 500);
    strcpy(f.riderName, temp);

    cout << "Rank: ";
    is >> f.rank;
    is.ignore(100000, "\n");

    cout << "Age: ";
    is >> f.age;
    is.ignore(100000, "\n");

    cout << "Weyr: ";
    is.getline(temp, 500);
    strcpy(f.weyr, temp);


    return is;

}


ofstream& operator << (ofstream& os, const FlyingUnit& f )
{
  os << f.dragonName << endl
     << f.dragonColour << endl
     << f.length << endl
     << f.wingspan << endl
     << f.breatheFire << endl
     << f.riderName << endl
     << f.rank << endl
     << f.age << endl
     << f.weyr << endl;

     return os;

}


ifstream& operator >> ( ifstream& is, FlyingUnit& f )
{
   char temp[500];

    is.getline(temp, 500);
    strcpy(f.dragonName, temp);


    is.getline(temp, 500);
    strcpy(f.dragonColour);


    is >> f.length;
    is.ignore(100000, "\n");


    is >> f.wingspan;
    is.ignore(100000, "\n");

    //cout << "Breathes Fire: ";
   // is.getline(temp, 500);


    is.getline(temp, 500);
    strcpy(f.riderName, temp);


    is >> f.rank;
    is.ignore(100000, "\n");


    is >> f.age;
    is.ignore(100000, "\n");


    is.getline(temp, 500);
    strcpy(f.weyr, temp);


    return is;
}
```

## EDIT

I will provide another class and .h file I've made and it works fine:

Rider.cpp

```
#include "rider.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

Rider::Rider( const char* name, int age, const char* rank, 
              const char* weyr ) : age( age )
{
    this->name = new char[ strlen(name) + 1 ];
    strcpy( this->name, name );

    this->rank = new char[ strlen( rank ) + 1 ];
    strcpy( this->rank, rank );

    this->weyr = new char[ strlen( weyr ) + 1 ];
    strcpy( this->weyr, weyr );
}

ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const Rider& r)
{
   os << "Rider name: " << r.name 
      << " Age: " << r.age
      << " Rank: " << r.rank 
      << " Weyr: " << r.weyr << endl;
   return os;
}

istream& operator >> ( istream& is, Rider& r )
{
    char temp[ 500 ];
    cout << "Enter Rider name >> ";
    is.getline( temp, 500 );
    r.name = new char[strlen( temp ) + 1 ];
    strcpy( r.name, temp ); 

    cout << "Enter Rider age >> ";
    is >> r.age;
    // clean up the newline left after the int read
    // as we are going to read text next.
    is.ignore( 100000, '\n' );

    cout << "Enter Rider rank >> " ;
    is.getline( temp, 500 );
    r.rank = new char[ strlen( temp ) + 1];
    strcpy( r.rank, temp );

    cout << "Enter Rider weyr >> " ;
    is.getline( temp, 500 );
    r.weyr = new char[ strlen( temp )  +1];
    strcpy( r.weyr, temp );

    return is;
}

ofstream& operator << ( ofstream& os, const Rider& r )
{
   os << r.name << endl
      << r.age << endl
      << r.rank << endl
      << r.weyr << endl;

   return os;
}

ifstream& operator >> ( ifstream& is, Rider & r )
{
    char temp[ 500 ];
    is.getline( temp, 500 );
    r.name = new char[ strlen( temp ) + 1 ];
    strcpy( r.name, temp );

    is >> r.age;

    is.ignore( 100000, '\n' );
    is.getline(temp, 500 );
    r.rank = new char[ strlen( temp ) + 1];
    strcpy( r.rank, temp );
    is.getline(temp, 500 );
    r.weyr = new char[ strlen( temp ) + 1 ];
    strcpy( r.weyr, temp );

    return is;
}
```

Rider.h

```
#ifndef RIDER_H
#define RIDER_H

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::boolalpha;

#include <cstring>
using std::strcpy;
using std::strlen;

#include <fstream>
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::ifstream;

class Rider
{
public:
    Rider( ) = default;
    Rider( const char* name, int age, const char* rank, const char* weyr );
    void setName( const char* name );
    void setRank( const char * rank );
    void setWeyr( const char * weyr );
    void setAge( int age ); // required when we enter a new Rider
                            // from the keyboard

    const char* getName( ) const { return name; }
    const char* getRank( ) const { return rank; }
    const char* getWeyr( ) const { return weyr; }
    int getAge( ) const { return age; }

    friend ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const Rider& r);
    friend istream& operator >> ( istream& is, Rider& r );
    friend ofstream& operator << ( ofstream& os, const Rider& r );
    friend ifstream& operator >> ( ifstream& is, Rider & r );
private:
    char * name = nullptr;
    char * rank = nullptr;
    char * weyr = nullptr;
    int age = 0;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Did you read the error? `class ‘FlyingUnit’ does not have any field named ‘length’` is pretty clear to me.

Comment: I cant provide the full error, its about 400 lines long, and says "'Class FlyingUnit' has no member named 'xxxxx' " for everything

Comment: @Burgtaro If you've developed this code, please compile more often, or use an IDE with intellisense.

Comment: All of those are members of `FlyingUnit`s members, not of `FlyingUnit`.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a member variable "double length" in your class FlyingUnit

- please note that in your contructor

  ```
  FlyingUnit::FlyingUnit( const char* dragonName, const char* dragonColour,
          double length, double wingspan, bool breatheFire,
          const char* riderName, const char* rank, int age,
          const char* weyr ) : length(length), wingspan(wingspan), age(age)
  ```

you try to initialize variables that don't exist; length, wingspan, and age ... try to declare those in your header ..

Comment: The error I've provided is an example, it happens to EVERY variable in the constructor

Comment: Look at the data members you define in the class. You are trying to access variables that aren't there.

Comment: @Burgtaro the answer he gave is just an example :P, also most of the other members are simply missing

Comment: yes, you are missing them all length, wingspan, age

Comment: I've done the exact same thing for 4 other classes and .h files and it works perfectly fine, this one for some reason doesn't recognise anything

Comment: @Burgtaro I strongly disbelieve that statement. You cant access  a member `X`  if the class has no member `X`

Comment: @Burgtaro if you show a small example of such a class, maybe we could help to solve the misunderstanding

Comment: @tobi303, Check the edit i've made to the question hopefully that clears it up!

Comment: @Burgtaro well, as expected in that other class you are **not** doing the exact same thing. You declare some member variables `name`,`rank`,`weyr` and `age` and you use **only** those

Comment: it works fine because you have "age" declared in your header Rider.h ! please read my answer and recheck your files...

Comment: Like I said this is all very new to me, thrown in the deep end with this project and I'm obviously all over the place... I'll check it all now :)

Comment: @Burgtaro do you know what a "member variable declaration" is? Maybe that is causing your confusion....

Comment: @tobi303 There is so much confusion for me right now after spending all night trying to do this... I have no idea what anything is any more lol